# Create table from table of column names and data types

Tags: sql, oracle, select, create-table, external-tables

Using the metadata table **USER_TAB_COLUMNS** I've obtained the column names and data types of one of my tables like so :

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'BACKUP'
AND column_name NOT IN ('ID', 'ENV_ID');
```

The result is as follows :

```
COLUMN_NAME        |DATA_TYPE
--------------------------------------
SESSION_STATION     NVARCHAR2
user                NVARCHAR2
type                NCHAR
date                DATE
hour                NVARCHAR2
```

What I'm looking to do is create a new external table with these column names and data types, as such :

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
(
    SESSION_STATION     NVARCHAR2
    user                NVARCHAR2
    type                NCHAR
    date                DATE
    hour                NVARCHAR2
)
organization external
(
    ...
);
```

I'd like to do this by using the result of the previous select during the creation of the new table instead of typing it out manually into the query.

I was hoping to do so simply like this, but it obviously **doesn't work** :

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
(
    SELECT column_name, data_type
    FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'BACKUP'
    AND column_name NOT IN ('ID', 'ENV_ID');
)
```

**N.B.** I **cannot** use "CREATE TABLE new_table AS" since it does not work with "organization external" when creating this as an external table.

The end goal of this is to have a client application send queries to the database to import different csv files into different tables by changing only the table and csv file name within each query.

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you!

Comment: Where do you get the information which is needed for `organization external` clause, e.g. the folder name.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit csv directory is managed by the client app in a preceding query creating the directory if it hasn't been done yet, the rest is mostly static (except for date format which I still have to figure out a way of making generic)

Answer (score 2):

Write query which will write query for you. For example:

```
SQL> select 'create table new_table (' result
  2    from dual union all
  3  select
  4    column_name ||' '||
  5    data_type   ||
  6    case when data_type = 'DATE' then null  -- no length for DATE datatype
  7         else '(' || data_length ||')'
  8    end         ||
  9    case when column_id = (select max(column_id)   -- omit comma for the last column
 10                           From user_tab_columns
 11                           where table_name = 'EMP')
 12                           then null
 13         else ','
 14    end
 15    from user_tab_columns
 16    where table_name = 'EMP'
 17  union all
 18  select ') organization external ...;'
 19  from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create table new_table (
EMPNO NUMBER(22),
ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
JOB VARCHAR2(9),
MGR NUMBER(22),
HIREDATE DATE,
SAL NUMBER(22),
COMM NUMBER(22),
DEPTNO NUMBER(22)
) organization external ...;

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Then copy/paste the result and execute it; I'll do it without the "external" suffix:

```
SQL> create table new_table (
  2  EMPNO NUMBER(22),
  3  ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
  4  JOB VARCHAR2(9),
  5  MGR NUMBER(22),
  6  HIREDATE DATE,
  7  SAL NUMBER(22),
  8  COMM NUMBER(22),
  9  DEPTNO NUMBER(22)
 10  ) ;

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, it seems crazy to me that there is no easy option implemented into Oracle to do this?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, there *is* a simpler way. If you use GUI (such as TOAD or SQL Developer), it offers the **Script** tab (when viewing certain tables) so - copy/paste that script and reuse it. It'll probably be better than the above (simple) principle I wrote in a matter of minutes because more complex datatypes make things more complex and this simple query might become a little monster.